# ECDSA parameters are not aligned between pem file and debug process

Tags: openssl, ecdsa

I create an ECDSA key pair by below command

1. openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -out secp256k1.pem
2. openssl ecparam -in secp256k1.pem -genkey -noout -out secp256k1-key.pem
3. openssl ec -in secp256k1-key.pem -pubout -out secp256k1-key-pub.pem

Then I sign a test binary with this key

4. openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -out sha256_out.bin pmu_msg.bin
5. openssl pkeyutl -sign -in sha256_out.bin -inkey secp256k1-key.pem -out sig_ecdsa.bin -pkeyopt digest:sha256
6. openssl pkeyutl -verify -in sha256_out.bin -sigfile sig_ecdsa.bin -pkeyopt digest:sha256 -pubin -inkey secp256k1-key-pub.pem

Everything goes fine until this step.
Then I use widbg to debug step.6 command to understand the entire verification flow.
I dump EC parameters from pem files first. 
When I check some variables in windbg; I feel confused because the value is not as my expectation.
E:\project\ecdsa\secp256k1>openssl ecparam -in secp256k1.pem -text -param_enc explicit -noout

Field Type: prime-field

Prime:

00:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:fe:ff:
ff:fc:2f

A: 0

B: 7 (0x7)

Generator (uncompressed):

04:79:be:66:7e:f9:dc:bb:ac:55:a0:62:95:ce:87:
0b:07:02:9b:fc:db:2d:ce:28:d9:59:f2:81:5b:16:
f8:17:98:48:3a:da:77:26:a3:c4:65:5d:a4:fb:fc:
0e:11:08:a8:fd:17:b4:48:a6:85:54:19:9c:47:d0:
8f:fb:10:d4:b8

Order:
00:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
ff:fe:ba:ae:dc:e6:af:48:a0:3b:bf:d2:5e:8c:d0:
36:41:41

Cofactor: 1 (0x1)

E:\project\ecdsa\secp256k1>openssl ec -in secp256k1-key.pem -text -noout

Private-Key: (256 bit)

priv:

8e:73:0d:3f:1b:91:84:46:08:37:e1:57:76:6f:3a:
0d:45:13:b0:47:e1:8a:4a:10:c0:e5:5e:00:2f:3b:
fd:98

pub:

04:90:66:38:2f:91:f9:08:32:36:fd:dd:21:8f:91:
ce:84:a8:94:54:a1:bd:10:48:05:20:40:7b:6d:77:
53:25:6f:39:b7:3c:30:0f:e4:9b:a0:40:ee:48:bf:
09:22:18:70:f4:cd:9b:b0:9d:7d:9c:d8:99:65:b6:
87:71:ef:ec:6c

ASN1 OID: secp256k1

From above output, I assume

generator point X is

79:be:66:7e:f9:dc:bb:ac:55:a0:62:95:ce:87:0b:07:
02:9b:fc:db:2d:ce:28:d9:59:f2:81:5b:16:f8:17:98:

generator point Y is

48:3a:da:77:26:a3:c4:65:5d:a4:fb:fc:0e:11:08:a8:
fd:17:b4:48:a6:85:54:19:9c:47:d0:8f:fb:10:d4:b8

For public key, assuming Qa = (da X Generator Point)
Qa point X is

90:66:38:2f:91:f9:08:32:36:fd:dd:21:8f:91:ce:84:
a8:94:54:a1:bd:10:48:05:20:40:7b:6d:77:53:25:6f:

Qa point Y is

39:b7:3c:30:0f:e4:9b:a0:40:ee:48:bf:09:22:18:70:
f4:cd:9b:b0:9d:7d:9c:d8:99:65:b6:87:71:ef:ec:6c

Then at openssl!ossl_ecdsa_verify_sig+0x40a [E:\project\openssl\openssl_v\openssl\crypto\ec\ecdsa_ossl.c @ 435]

I dump public key X/Y from eckey structure

0:000:x86> ?? eckey->pub_key->X->d

unsigned int * 0x006b17e0

0:000:x86> db 0x006b17e0

006b17e0 d5 7e 76 7a b0 6e d0 1d-fe 56 63 ab 47 45 27 1b .~vz.n...Vc.GE'.

006b17f0 e9 7c 09 94 99 bb 6a 6e-c5 24 66 4e be 75 15 a8 .|....jn.$fN.u..

006b1800 fd fd fd fd ab ab ab ab-ab ab ab ab ee fe ee fe ................

0:000:x86> ?? eckey->pub_key->Y->d

unsigned int * 0x006b1840

0:000:x86> db 0x006b1840

006b1840 f8 42 f5 18 3e c5 d4 18-29 4d c9 a5 e1 c9 2c e2 .B..>...)M....,.

006b1850 c6 e2 ec cf 82 b9 85 d6-56 37 64 e8 0c 4f 31 54 ........V7d..O1T

006b1860 fd fd fd fd ab ab ab ab-ab ab ab ab ee fe ee fe ................

From windbbg,
public key, point X =

d5 7e 76 7a b0 6e d0 1d-fe 56 63 ab 47 45 27 1b
e9 7c 09 94 99 bb 6a 6e-c5 24 66 4e be 75 15 a8

But in pem file, point x is

90:66:38:2f:91:f9:08:32:36:fd:dd:21:8f:91:ce:84:
a8:94:54:a1:bd:10:48:05:20:40:7b:6d:77:53:25:6f:

public key, point Y =

f8 42 f5 18 3e c5 d4 18-29 4d c9 a5 e1 c9 2c e2 
c6 e2 ec cf 82 b9 85 d6-56 37 64 e8 0c 4f 31 54

But in pem file, point Y is

39:b7:3c:30:0f:e4:9b:a0:40:ee:48:bf:09:22:18:70:
f4:cd:9b:b0:9d:7d:9c:d8:99:65:b6:87:71:ef:ec:6c

These values are not as same as what I saw in public pem file.

Then I dump generator point in windbg and have same doubt.

0:000:x86> ?? eckey->group->generator->X->d unsigned int * 0x006b13c0

0:000:x86> db 0x006b13c0

006b13c0 97 20 7e 48 5a 2e 36 d7-db 66 bc 29 53 29 1e 23 . ~HZ.6..f.)S).#

006b13d0 9c 12 fd 33 c0 48 9f 97-48 9f 08 e9 43 e6 81 99 ...3.H..H...C...

006b13e0 fd fd fd fd ab ab ab ab-ab ab ab ab ee fe ee fe ................

0:000:x86> ?? eckey->group->generator->Y->d unsigned int * 0x006b1420

0:000:x86> db 0x006b1420

006b1420 e2 ab db d3 d2 a6 5e b1-4d c6 1d 1f 5d 5d fc 8d ......^.M...]]..

006b1430 36 c1 19 ac 9a b5 b6 70-d6 82 a5 d4 1f 85 3f cf 6......p......?.

006b1440 fd fd fd fd ab ab ab ab-ab ab ab ab ee fe ee fe ................

Could anyone please give me some comments?

Thanks

Comment: This would be much easier to read if you used 'code' format (and no extra lines) for the computer input-and-output. And you should use it for the example commands, although it is less necessary there. In the editor click the circled questionmark and then the 'Code' tab for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL maintains the coordinates of elliptic-curve points internally in [**Montgomery form**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_modular_multiplication) to allow more efficient computation -- and also uses projective rather than affine coordinates, although that doesn't matter at this point since no real computation has been done yet and Z is just encoded(1). See [`ec_GFp_simple_set_Jprojective_coordinates_GFp` in `ecp_smpl.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/ec/ecp_smpl.c#L375) and note the `group->meth->field_encode` steps which resolve to [`ec_GFp_mont_field_encode` in `ecp_mont.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/ec/ecp_mont.c#L266) which uses the macro `BN_to_montgomery` which expands to call [`BN_mod_mul_montgomery` in `bn_mont.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/bn/bn_mont.c#L26).

OpenSSL code is written for efficiency, not ease of reading. And being C adds more clutter. Plus most of it still follows the tradition set by EAY of terse names and almost no comments. If you want to learn from debugging -- although frankly I doubt you'll get any more than you would from the specifications and probably less, because the interesting parts of ECC are in the math not the code -- I suggest Java, or C# with BouncyCastle.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Because we have HW engine to accelerate Modular Multiplication, Modular Addition .. etc; help to  reduce calculation effort for SW.  I would like to generate signature and follow https://andrea.corbellini.name/2015/05/30/elliptic-curve-cryptography-ecdh-and-ecdsa/ to validate signature with HW engine.  Given  r. s , and hash and all parameters from .pem file. I assume the intermediate output values should be  as same as the  variables  saved in openssl EC structure. But since openssl used projective coordinate rather than affine coordinate; we can't use openssl as reference model.